# Apache error with C CGI program

Tags: c, apache, cgi

I'm attempting to write a CGI program in C (I'm learning and it seemed like something fun to do) and I'm having a problem with an Apache/CGI error but only with one very specific line. If this particular line is commented or removed it works perfectly fine but if it's included it bombs every single time.

```
struct site_link
{
    char *name;
    char *url;
};

struct blog_data
{
    char *blog_name;
    struct site_link *links;
} blog;

blog.blog_name = "richardwagner.io";
blog.links[0].url = "Home"; // <-- this line right here
blog.links[0].name = "Home";
blog.links[1].url = "Posts";
blog.links[1].name = "Posts";
blog.links[2].url = "About";
blog.links[2].name = "About";
```

And the Apache log with 'debug' level logging turned on.

```
[Mon Dec 15 10:27:38.906961 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 63010] mod_authz_core.c(799): [client 192.168.1.104:49922] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 15 10:27:38.906982 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 63010] mod_authz_core.c(799): [client 192.168.1.104:49922] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Dec 15 10:27:38.907020 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 63010] mod_authz_core.c(799): [client 192.168.1.104:49922] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 15 10:27:38.907026 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 63010] mod_authz_core.c(799): [client 192.168.1.104:49922] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Dec 15 10:27:39.186804 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 63010] [client 192.168.1.104:49922] End of script output before headers: tblog
```

I've been trying to work this out for a few days and I just can't get it to play nice with that one line, even though, to me, it seems almost identical to the other few lines below it.

Comment: I knew I'd forget something. I also have the Content-type blah-blah line well before any of this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing \r\n\r\n to signify the end of the headers.

Comment: As in:
printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"); //???

The errors produced and logged are the same.

Comment: Run your CGI on the command line and put the output in a pastebin/gist